# How to check whether a context menu or dropdown list is opened in the current window?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to check if there is any context menu or dropdown list opened in the current window. There is a `QTimer` running that should do its work only if there is no "blocking" context menu or dropdown list opened.

When the menu/list is opened, I cannot click any other controls in that window. First the framework will close the menu/list, and after that I can click the control. Thus I think the winow itself knows about the state of the menu/list controls. How to get that state?

Comment: you can get a signal from a dropdown if ther is opened.

Comment: I would consider to re-implement  [QWidget::contextMenuEvent(QContextMenuEvent *event)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#contextMenuEvent)  , and log window state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by checking whether [QApplication.activePopupWidget()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#activePopupWidget) returns `None` inside the slot connected to your timer. This will work with both meus and drop-down widgets. There's also [QApplication.activeModalWidget()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#activeModalWidget) that does the same thing for modal dialogs, if that's relevant.

Here is a simple demo script:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.combo = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.combo.addItems('One Two Three'.split())
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Open Menu')
        menu = QtWidgets.QMenu()
        menu.addAction('Something')
        self.button.setMenu(menu)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addWidget(self.combo)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.setInterval(200)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.handleTimeout)
        self.timer.start()

    def handleTimeout(self):
        if QtWidgets.qApp.activePopupWidget() is None:
            self.label.setText(QtCore.QTime.currentTime().toString())
        else:
            self.label.setText('Popup detected!')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(600, 100, 200, 150)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```